# OpenCV Yolo V3 tiny

Tags: opencv, yolo

I am trying to use Yolo tiny on Open CV 3.4.1 Can anyone confirm whether it is supported?

I get an error when reading the config file - I am using yolov3-tiny.weights and yolov3-tiny.cfg downloaded from

https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Parsing error (Unknown layer type: yolo) in bool cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgFile(const char*, cv::dnn::darknet::NetParameter*), file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp, line 503 07-02 12:10:21.455 31240-31240/ E/org.opencv.dnn: dnn::readNetFromDarknet_10() caught cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.1) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/darknet/darknet_io.cpp:503: error: (-212) Unknown layer type: yolo in function bool cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgFile(const char*, cv::dnn::darknet::NetParameter*)
```

Answer (score 2):

As of April 16, yes, it is supported (pull request [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11322)). I don't know what your code looks like, but it seems like [someone else](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11310) had the same problem and was able to resolve it. If this doesn't help, feel free to post some code you have and we can give it a look.